# How to Determine Bandwidth in HTML5 Using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I have a simple function in javascript which I would like to use to return the bandwidth to my application in C#. For some reason when calling InvokeScript I am getting a SystemException but I am not sure why. My code is below

C#

```
private void RunTestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Bandwidth
        object bandwidth = Browser.InvokeScript("getBandwidth"); //SystemException Error
    }

private void Browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        string value = e.Value;

        BandwidthTextBlock.Text = value;
    }
```

the JavaScript function

```
//Bandwidth
    function getBandwidth() {
        var connection = navigator.connectionSpeed;
        window.external.notify(connection.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work in Chrome and Firefox, not in IE as of this time.